# What's the term for a class that cannot be instantiated on its own?

Tags: vba

For example, a dictionary object can be be created just by using the "New" keyword:

```
 Dim dic as Scripting.Dictionary
 Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

But the "Sort" class needs to be added using a worksheet property:

```
 'This won't work
 Dim srt as Excel.Sort
 Set srt = New Excel.Sort
 'This will work
 Dim srt as Excel.Sort
 Set srt = Activesheet.sort
```

What's also interesting as that when trying to incorrectly instantiate the srt object in the above example using the New Keyword, Intellisense will not show Excel.Sort as an option.  However, if you incorrectly instantiate a new workbook object using the new keyword Intellisense does show Excel.Workbook as an option.

Comment: `Sort` and `Workbook` are examples of interface.

Comment: @MatthewD: that's not it. It's not the difference between modules and class modules, but between class modules with different instancing.

Answer (score 2):

The term is called [`"noncreatable"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367118(v=vs.85).aspx). It's an attribute you can add to the definition of the `coclass`.

```
[
  coclass-attribute-list, 
    noncreatable
]
coclass coclass-name
{
  coclass-interface-list
}
```

As the above documentation mentions, it's used to create COM classes that can't be instantiated on their own using `CreateInstance()` or `CoCreateInstance()` (in VBA, this translates to `CreateObject()`, which calls one of those two functions). But you can still obtain a reference to an existing COM object, as you've shown above:

```
Set srt = Activesheet.sort
```

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, the term is `PublicNotCreatable`.

Here's a good link: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx (look at the section "The Instancing Property Of A Class").

If you've created a class module, then in the Properties window you can change the instancing from `Private` (the default) to `PublicNotCreatable`, and you'll get this behavior.

Generally, you'd provide a factory method on another class that allows users of your library to create instances of those classes under controlled circumstances. Or of course you could prevent users of your library from creating them at all, if that's what you want.